# design edit text in exact rectangular shape android linear layout without hard coding values

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to **design**

[image: this]

layout i.e. width of edit text should be like this. For the following code

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_below="@+id/txt_buy_info"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_space"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgound"
        android:hint="Rate"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/BTC_value_size"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_inr_24"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgound"
        android:hint="Amount"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_internal_space"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/BTC_value_size"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_inr_24"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgound"
        android:hint="Quantity"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_internal_space"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/BTC_value_size"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_bitcoin_24"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff61fffd"
        android:hint="Rate"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_internal_space"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/BTC_value_size"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_inr_24"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

it is giving **output** like

[image: this]

When I give match_parent to both width and height to inner linear layout, it does not look good, and when I tried to give left and right padding to inner linear layout the design becomes bad.I want to design this layout without giving the hard coded width.Please help

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_below="@+id/txt_buy_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Rate"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlack"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Amount"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlack"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Quantity"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlack"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff61fffd"
            android:hint="Rate"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlack"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can remove weight from every AppCompatEditText and AppCompatButton. If you dont want to fill whole screen.

Comment: Yes exactly I want this. Thanks for your valuable reply

Answer (score 0):

remove unnecessary weights `android:layout_weight="1"` and add padding `android:padding="10dp"` to Edittexts
like below

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_below="@+id/txt_buy_info"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_space"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgound"
        android:hint="Rate"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/BTC_value_size"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_inr_24"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgound"
        android:hint="Amount"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_internal_space"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/BTC_value_size"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_inr_24"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgound"
        android:hint="Quantity"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_internal_space"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/BTC_value_size"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_bitcoin_24"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff61fffd"
        android:hint="Rate"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_internal_space"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/BTC_value_size"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_inr_24"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  // Change layout_width= "match_parent"  // it will work fine
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgound"
        android:hint="Rate"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/BTC_value_size"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_inr_24"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgound"
        android:hint="Amount"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_internal_space"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/BTC_value_size"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_inr_24"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_backgound"
        android:hint="Quantity"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_internal_space"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/BTC_value_size"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_bitcoin_24"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff61fffd"
        android:hint="Rate"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_internal_space"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/BTC_value_size"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_inr_24"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

//Please check the comment on 4th line i have mentioned.